# Js function return undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, scope, return

I'm building a small reporting tool with Node.js and I am facing some scoping problems with Javascript. I am calling a function and it should return a array with cities from a database query. Here the function.

```
function queryBuilderZone () {
  var includedCities = new Array();
  q = heredoc(function(){/*
        SELECT majlis.MajlisId
        FROM majlis
        WHERE majlis.ZoneId = -ZONE-
  */});
  q = q.replace(/-ZONE-/g, inZone);

  connection.query(q, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var rowsLentgh = rows.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < rowsLentgh; i++) {
              includedCities.unshift(rows[i].MajlisId);
        };
        console.log(includedCities); // <-- output correct: ['...', '....']
  });
  connection.end();
  console.log(includedCities); // <-- output wrong: []
  return includedCities;
```

}

This is my call from the main program

```
 includedCities = queryBuilderZone();
 console.log(includedCities); // <-- output wrong: []
```

Where is the problem and why is this function not returning the elements in the array `includedCities`?
And in the scope of `connection.query` it shows the correct and expected value.

*By the way I am using the `mysql` module for building the query and replacing the placeholder in the query.*

Comment: Standard async case. Your "faulty" console log occurs before the callback is done? And "includeCities" is a variable local to your function.

Comment: It seems to me this is a scoping problem. I am not a node.js person, but includeCities is defined within the queryBuilderZone function, which is not in the global scope. Move it above the function into the global scope.

Comment: @rontornambe this is a very typical problem of a node.js beginner who haven't found the time to read a small tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's going on here is the difference between a return and a callback. Due to the fact that the `connection.query()` function is having to reach out to get its information, the `queryBuilderZone()` function will continue on after it initiates it, and then reach the conclusion that `includedCities` is and empty Array, because it is at that time.

What you want to do is pass in a callback to queryBuilderZone, something like this

```
function queryBuilderZone(callback) {
    var includedCities = new Array();
    q = heredoc(function () {
        /*
        SELECT majlis.MajlisId
        FROM majlis
        WHERE majlis.ZoneId = -ZONE-
  */
    });
    q = q.replace(/-ZONE-/g, inZone);

    connection.query(q, function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var rowsLentgh = rows.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < rowsLentgh; i++) {
            includedCities.unshift(rows[i].MajlisId);
        };
        console.log(includedCities); // <-- output correct: ['...', '....']
        callback(includedCities);
    });
    connection.end();
    console.log(includedCities); // <-- output wrong: []
    // return includedCities; Not needed
}
```

Then when you want to utilize it, you'd do so like this.

```
queryBuilderZone(function(includedCities) {
    // Do what you'd like here
    console.log(includedCities); // <-- output correct: ['...', '....']
});
```

Whatever's in the callback function will be executed after `connection.query` runs its course, and spits out the array.

Comment: thanks! I didn't know about callbacks. Therefore I am just trying to learn and solve the problem at the same time. Although I could solve it with other languages. I you have any good tutorial for callback then don't hesitate to share it :)